# jQuery font picker in add block form dialog submits form instead of selecting font

Tags: jquery, google-fonts, concrete5-8.x

I want to use the Google Font Picker ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-picker ) in the Add Block form dialog (part of Concrete5 CMS). But when I click on the font picker select, it submits the form instead of simply selecting the font. Seems like a JS conflict between the font picker select event and the form dialog submit.

Anyone know how to fix that?

Thank you.

Code (part of Add Block form dialog which pops up with JS):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?php
    echo $form->label('font', t('Select text font family'));
    ?>
    <div id="font-picker"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <p class="apply-font">Image text preview</p>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){    
    const fontPicker = new FontPicker(
    'Google-API-key', // Google API key
    'Open Sans', // default font
    {limit: 50}, // additional options
  );
});
</script>
```

[SOLVED]

Thanks to Terry:

```
$('#ccm-block-form').on("click", ":submit", function(e) {
    if (e.target.id !== 'ccm-form-submit-button')
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.target` actually references a DOM node, not a jQuery object. You should compare it to the DOM node returned from the jQuery object by appending a `[0]` to it:

```
if (e.target !== $('#ccm-form-submit-button')[0]) { ... }
```

Alternatively, a simpler way is simply to check the target's ID:

```
if (e.target.id !== 'ccm-form-submit-button') { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you, Terry. That worked. But one issue - the form is now submitted twice. (I'll update the post)

Comment: @linuxoid You're welcome! I found a typo in my answer, I just corrected it ;)